# What happens when a DocuSign envelope-level Connect event (created via the API) exhausts all retries?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

If an envelope-level (vs account-level) Connect event created via the API with RequireAcknowledgement set to TRUE exhausts all retries, what happens?

In the support article, "[Connect Failures and Retries](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=qmr1583277386549.html&_LANG=enus)", it mentions, "Administrators can choose to receive email notifications. You receive two proactive emails and another email at deactivation.". However, it seems like that applies to account-level Connect configurations, not envelope-level Connect events created through the API.

Basically, I'm trying to determine what happens after the 15-day mark, when all retries have been exhausted. Ideally, I'd receive an email notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 15 days we will no longer auto-retry events and those specific events will need to be manually retried via the [republish tool](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=boq1583277458468.html&_LANG=enus) in the UI or with our new [Republish API call](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopepublish/createhistoricalenvelopepublishtransaction/).

Envelope-level Connect configurations are not being auto-disabled at this time so there will be no email notification.

Comment: I would add that it never hurts to set up a periodic "check failures" call (via API) to check to see if the Failures log has any entries ( GET /connect/failures).  If there are any, your code can send an email alert to the admins.  This is something that you can set up to execute once every few days or so.  ANY failures are worth investigating.